# Sending an email using oath2 credentials requires further authorization

Tags: python, gmail-api

I'm writing a simple python program to send an email automatically.
I've already set up the project on the google cloud console and downloaded the credentials.json on my folder.

What I got now is:

```
import base64
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from requests import HTTPError

SCOPES = ["www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send"]
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)

service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
message = MIMEText('This is the body of the email')
message['to'] = 'reciever@gmail.com'
message['subject'] = 'Test'
create_message = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}

try:
    message = (service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
    print(F'sent message to {message} Message Id: {message["id"]}')
except HTTPError as error:
    print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
    message = None
```

The "credentials.json" file is the one downloaded from the console.cloud.google.com page after creating the credential for a desktop application.

This program manages to send me an email, but I need to access to my google account when I run it.

Is there a way to make a program that sends an email without the need for someone to be there to confirm the account to log into?

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if you have Google Workspace, there is an option called [impersonation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests) (delegate domain-wide authority) to send emails using a services account on behalf of the user without having to sign-in.

To do this you will need to create a services account first inside of your GCP project, and a Key for the services account. You can see the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#creatinganaccount). Then download the JSON for the Key. I named my file `serviceaccount.JSON`.

You need to set up a Domain wide delegation in the Admin console of Google. You can see the steps [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#delegatingauthority).

Here is a sample code using a services account and impersonation to sent emails:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import base64
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import google.auth
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.oauth2 import service_account



def gmail_send_message():

    SCOPES = ['www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send']
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'serviceaccount.json'

    creds  = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
            SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
            scopes=SCOPES,

            # user that will be impersonated to send emails
            subject='user@domain.com') 

    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        message =  MIMEText('This is the body of the email')
        message['To'] = 'reciever@gmail.com'
        message['Subject'] = 'Test'

        # encoded message
        encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()) \
            .decode()

        create_message = {
            'raw': encoded_message
        }
        # pylint: disable=E1101
        send_message = (service.users().messages().send
                        (userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
        print(F'sent message to {message} Message Id: {message["id"]}')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        send_message = None
    return send_message


if __name__ == '__main__':
    gmail_send_message()
```

Another option, without using workspace is to change this part of the code:

```
flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES) creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
```

For:

```
creds = None
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
        token.write(creds.to_json())
```

Which will reuse the token file created until it expires. However, you will need to sign-in manually the first time.